# jqGrid fill up from stored procedure + SQL Server 2008 + MVC (without using model) -- Updated with sample code for better understanding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, jqgrid

I want to fill jqGrid from a stored procedure, there was 1 good example is given at following link, but my problem is that I am not using model to retrieve data, any SOLUTION ?

I am using jqGrid + SQL Server 2008 + ASP.net MVC3 (c#)

[Example of jqGrid filling by stored procedure with Model](http://wyousuf.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/jqgrid-with-asp-net-mvc-and-ms-sqloracle-store-procedure/)

Here by am giving the code that i am using currently

## **VIEW CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#History').jqGrid({
            //url from wich data should be requested
            url: '@Url.Action("UploadData")?entity=' + getEntity(),

            //type of data
            datatype: 'json',
            //url access method type
            mtype: 'GET',
            //columns names
            colNames: ['ID', 'File','Uploaded', 'By'],
            //columns model
            colModel: [
                            { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', align: 'left', editable: false },
                            { name: 'File', index: 'File', align: 'left', editable: false, formatter: "text", width: '105px' },
                            { name: 'Uploaded', index: 'Uploaded', align: 'left', editable: false, formatter: "text", width: '102px' },
                            { name: 'By', index: 'By', align: 'left', editable: false, formatter: "text", width: '78px' },
                          ],
            //pager for grid
            pager: $('#Historypager'),
            //number of rows per page
            rowNum: 15,
            //initial sorting column
            sortname: 'File',
            //initial sorting direction
            sortorder: 'asc',
            //we want to display total records count
            viewrecords: true,
            //Sets the caption for grid
            caption: 'Upload History',
            //grid height
            height: '100%'

        });

        $('#History').jqGrid('navGrid', '#Historypager', { add: false, del: false, edit: false, search: false });

        $('#History').jqGrid('hideCol', "ID");
        var dialogPosition = $(this).offset();
    });
```

## **CONTROLLER METHOD**

```
public JsonResult UploadData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, string entity)
        {
            int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
            int pageSize = rows;
            var entitytype = Request.QueryString["entity"].ToString().Trim();
            var uploadlist = objEntities.Uploads.Where(u => u.TableName == entitytype).ToList().AsQueryable(); // fetches the data from upload table

            int totalRecords = uploadlist.ToList().Count(); // total records in the current table
            int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize); // counts the total no. of pages

            if (sord.Trim().ToLower() == "asc") // fetches data according the sorting order
                uploadlist = uploadlist.OrderBy(x => TypeHelper.GetPropertyValue(x, sidx)).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            else
                uploadlist = uploadlist.OrderByDescending(x => TypeHelper.GetPropertyValue(x, sidx)).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

            // fetches data and sets it in JSON format
            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                page = page,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = (from b1 in uploadlist
                        select new
                        {
                            id = b1.ID,
                            cell = new string[] {
                                Convert.ToString(b1.ID),
                                b1.File,
                                Convert.ToString(b1.Uploaded),
                                Convert.ToString(b1.By)
                            }
                        }).ToArray()
            };

            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); // returns the data back to the jqgrid
        }
```

In this Example i've used LINQ demo, but now in new task i've to use Stored Procedure to fetch the data...

Comment: If you are not using a model what are you using to retrieve the data?

Comment: using JSON, i do call method of controller and retrieve data in form of JSON object

Comment: Would you like to show some code?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov : hi, i've attached the sample code that am using

Comment: @ITppl now your are fetching data from stored procedure ? and getting the result as object type ?

Comment: @ITppl i had done this with Lib.web.mvc dll (open source), i m sharing a code snippet , might be it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CONTROLLER CODE

```
var uploadlist = SPforData(sidx, sord, page, rows /* , +other parameters */).ToList();
                int totalRecords = 0;
                foreach (var pr in uploadlist)
                {
                    totalRecords = Convert.ToInt32(pr.Total);
                    break;
                } // here I am fetching total number of records that have been returned from SP

        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize); // counts the total no. of pages

        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = (from pr in uploadlist
                    select new
                    {
                        id = pr.ID,
                        cell = new string[] {
                            Convert.ToString(pr.ID),
                            Convert.ToString(pr.Name),
                            Convert.ToString(pr.Age),
                            Convert.ToString(pr.Qualification),
                        }
                    }).ToArray()
        };

        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); // returns the data back to the jqgrid
```

Answer (score 1):

[Lib.Web.Mvc](https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc)

The code sample is here:
Create a list of JQgridRow

```
List<JqGridRow> jqgRows = new List<JqGridRow>();
```

Get the records from ur SP

```
var Rows = GetrecordsfromSP(parameters);

foreach (object[] row in Rows)
{
    jqgRows.Add(new JqGridRow()
    {
        id = row[0].ToString(), //depend on your columns
        cell = new[] {
            row[0].ToString(),
            row[1].ToString(),
            row[2].ToString(),
            row[3].ToString(),
        }
    }
}

var GetData = new
{
total = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)TotalRecs / (float)request.rows),
                page = request.page,
                records = TotalRecs,
                rows = jqgRows.ToArray()

};

return Json(GetData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Hope this will help, note in the DLL JqgridRow i think replaced with JqGridRecord, but i m not sure about it.

Thanks

Comment: hi, I've found alternate solution which doesn't require any external DLL, and this code is working fine for me, Your solution is also fine ... :) thanks for your help and time